# SLIME on Emacs with paredit in repl - how to prevent execution of incomplete but balanced expressions?

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, slime, paredit

I use paredit on emacs with SLIME's repl. This means that at any point during my typing on the repl, my s-expressions are balanced.

However, they may not be complete, and I might want to continue typing inside them in another line, as follows:

```
CL-USER> (defun print-hello ()
            )
```

When I start a new line by pressing the enter key, however, the SLIME repl executes my incomplete expression. I want it to wait for me to complete the expression, as follows:

```
CL-USER> (defun print-hello ()
            (format t "Hello, world"))
```

How do I make this happen please?

Comment: Use `C-j` instead.

Comment: That worked. Thanks!

Comment: Also consider using the slime scratch buffer for multi line expressions, much more convenient than the real

Answer (score 2):

For that situations, when writing long s-expressions in REPL I think that the best way is to use the [slime scratch buffer](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Scratch-Buffer.html). you can edit it and after that execute with

> C-j

No problem pressing enter inside the buffer, I'm using sly but the capture could be like this:

```
(defun print-hello ()
            (format t "Hello, world"))
 ; => PRINT-HELLO
```

Also another alternative is working without the last parent :-(

or as suggested in a comment by @jkiisky, type the expression and add in the middle of the s expression `C-j`

```
CL-USER> (defun
)
```

Comment: Thanks - the last part, using C-j instead of enter when writing an expression worked for me too

Answer (score 1):

Related to your question, [lispy](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy) provides integration with SLIME.

I typically never type anything into the REPL buffer. Instead, I edit all code in place in the source file, and use <kbd>e</kbd> to eval the current sexp.

`lispy` is also a super-set of `paredit`, if compatibility is your concern.