# Doom Emacs: Don't want auto complete in Slime-REPL

Tags: emacs, lisp, slime

This question is exactly opposite to the below question.

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987489/is-it-possible-to-auto-complete-parentheses-or-quotation-marks-in-emacs).

When I use **Slime** inside **Doom Emacs**, I am not able to type

```
(defun square (x)
   (* x x))
```

By the time I type `(defun square (x))`, two brackets are auto-completed, and when I etype `enter`, `slime REPL` is showing:

```
CL-USER> (defun square (x))
; in: DEFUN SQUARE
;     (SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA SQUARE
;         (X)
;       (BLOCK SQUARE))
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable X is defined but never used.
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
SQUARE
```

I don't know, which package **DOOM** is using for **auto-complete** and how to **disable** it?

Comment: it sounds like you want to disable just matching parens, not general autocompletion? It looks like it uses `smartparens`, so try `M-x smartparens-mode` in the slime buffer. Also, you should be able to use `open-line`, bound to `C-o` in normal emacs to get a newline even with smartparens

Comment: I press `C-j` to add newlines, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/47283937/124319

Comment: Answer is in Doom's FAQ. https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/develop/docs/faq.org#how-to-disable-smartparensautomatic-parentheses-completion

Comment: Thank you all.  Now I have three solutions.

Comment: `C-o` is not working for me.  But `C-j` is working.  For the third answer, when we disable globally using  `(after! smartparens (smartparens-global-mode -1))`, I am not getting smart parenthesis even in normal lisp editor. I prefer the first answer.

Comment: @SreekumarR -- the the link from the third comment above explicitly says _not_ to use `after!` as that is an outdated method. The link suggests using `(remove-hook 'doom-first-buffer-hook #'smartparens-global-mode)` instead.